# Poner en la primera opción de un DropDownList vacío en ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp

en mi pagina aspx tengo un DropDownList que es llenado con un DataSourse, este me visualiza los datos de un campo en la bd llamado nombre y su valor es el ID de los registros, lo que quiero saber es que puedo hacer para que el primer item del DropDownList sea un campo vacío o con un mensaje por ejemplo "--Seleccione una opción --" y respectivamente los siguientes items sean el valor del datasource anexo el codigo que tengo:

```
<label for="dlarea">Area:</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="dlarea" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataRA" DataTextField="nombre" DataValueField="id_area"></asp:DropDownList>
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataRA" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:conexionR %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [nombre], [id_area] FROM [t_area]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el event "DataBound" como asi

el control en la página web:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployee" runat="server" [etc...] OnDataBound="ddl_DataBound">
```

y en el code-behind

```
Protected Sub ddl_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
     Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)
     ddl.Items.Insert(0, "Select...")
End Sub
```

Nota: El cero pone "Select" al principio de la lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió bastante